# Mocking with RN Detox

Tags: typescript, react-native, e2e-testing, detox, metro-bundler

I am following the [detox mocking guide](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Guide.Mocking.md) with typescript. The app always prints console.log of `X.ts` file instead of `X.e2e.ts` file.

Dependency version.

```
react-native: 0.61.5,
detox: 16.4.0
```

Metro Configuration:

```
"detox": {
    "test-runner": "jest",
    "runner-config": "e2e/config.json",
    "configurations": {
      "ios.sim.debug": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.app",
        "build": "RN_SRC_EXT=e2e.js,e2e.ts xcodebuild -workspace ios/App.xcworkspace -scheme 'App Test' -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "device": {
          "type": "iPhone 11"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

metro.config.js

```
const defaultSourceExts = require("metro-config/src/defaults/defaults").sourceExts;

module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false
      }
    })
  },
  resolver: {
    sourceExts: process.env.RN_SRC_EXT ? process.env.RN_SRC_EXT.split(",").concat(defaultSourceExts) : defaultSourceExts
  }
};

console.log("default", defaultSourceExts);
console.log("module.exports from e2e", module.exports);

/** above console results into the following

default [ 'js', 'json', 'ts', 'tsx' ]
module.exports from e2e { transformer:
   { getTransformOptions: [AsyncFunction: getTransformOptions] },
  resolver: { sourceExts: [ 'e2e.ts', 'js', 'json', 'ts', 'tsx' ] } }
*/
```

/src/AppEvent.js

```
const logEvent = (): void => {
  console.log("from non-test event file");
};

export default {
  logEvent
};
```

/src/AppEvent.e2e.ts

```
const logEvent = (): void => {
  console.log("from test event file");
};

export default {
  logEvent
};
```

When I run `detox build && detox test` metro server doesn't log e2d files, So I had to run metro separately using `RN_SRC_EXT=e2e.js,e2e.ts yarn start`

Comment: I have problems with same version of react-native using mocking. Does your metro config works well? Looks its not replacing the .e2e files for prod ones.. @NAUSHAD

Comment: Also experiencing this, did you come up with a fix @naushad or @robto09?

Comment: @EricCarmichael I switch to Appium man.

Answer (score 0):

ive tried this method too but it was more boilerplate than tests, check this out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/10mock you can look at example code here: https://github.com/10play/10mock-example-app

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a slightly different version of config maybe this will help for anybody finding this as reference.
Config:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('metro-config');

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts },
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  let resolverSourceExts = [...sourceExts, 'svg', 'cjs'];
  // mocking setup for detox
  if (process.env.RN_SRC_EXT) {
    resolverSourceExts =
      process.env.RN_SRC_EXT.split(',').concat(resolverSourceExts);
  }
  return {
    transformer: {
      getTransformOptions: async () => ({
        transform: {
          experimentalImportSupport: false,
          inlineRequires: true,
        },
      }),
    },
    resolver: {
      sourceExts: resolverSourceExts,
    },
  };
})();
```

I have faced a similar issue with components not being picked up after migrating to TS. Apparently, my components were all **TSX** not TS files.

I changed my `RN_SRC_EXT` to `e2e.tsx` and it worked flawlessly.